# how to perform a proper query with PromQL to get an increasing rate in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-alertmanager

Here I have a requirement.

If the response time of an Url keeps going up in a short-time-period-average, which means the increase rate is larger than 0, I need to raise an alert to warn that this url may be facing a potential danger, and then take some degrade or flow-limitation methods.

While testing, I have a metric named `responseTime_POST__prometheus_webhook__test_prometheus_qps_stable` and `responseTime_POST__prometheus_webhook__test_prometheus_qps_increasing`. I will call them `increaseUrl` and `stableUrl` in a short name for read afterwards.

`increaseUrl` and `stableUrl` are set as `Gauge` to show the response time of 2 testing url.

Each time I request `increaseUrl`'s api, the response time is set to response with time-step increasing by 1 milisecond. To pretend this api do not have ability to process such quantity of requests.

And Each time I request `stableUrl`'s api, there are no other settings, just return succeed immediately.

It is OK to query derivation of response time of both `increaseUrl` and `stableUrl` by PromQL:
`deriv(responseTime_POST__prometheus_webhook__test_prometheus_qps_stable[10s])`
`deriv(responseTime_POST__prometheus_webhook__test_prometheus_qps_increasing[10s])`

 The graph is also rather reasonable that `stableUrl` will have a little vibration around value 0，and `increaseUrl` is always have a value larger than 0.5 which means the response time is going up.

In this picture, top is `stableUrl` and bottom is `increaseUrl`. by using `> 0` judgement, You can see the graph of `increasUrl` will always larger than 0, and `stableUrl` will not have that situation.
[image]

So I think, If I set an alert to judge derivation of response time and let the result `> 0` to be true for a while, I can then get a correct alert of `increaseUrl` and do some process afterwards.

It is OK if I'm using alert like this:

```
groups:
- name: automatic_flow_control
  rules:
  - alert: automatic_flow_control
    expr: deriv(responseTime_POST__prometheus_webhook__test_prometheus_qps_stable[15s])>0.1
    for: 1m
    labels:
      serverity: warn
    annotations:
      summary: gateway limitation alert has invoked
      value: "value= {{ $value }}"
```

But actually, I have a bunch of urls and I have to manage them all with this alert. So I decide to use expr `deriv(label_replace({__name__=~"responseTime.*"}, "metricname", "$1", "__name__", "(.*)")[20s:1s])>0.2` to do such job.

As I think this query will find out all metrics with name starts with `responseTime` and draw a
simple derivation map according to 4 points average( my prometheus scrape interval is 5s, which means 20s will contains 4 points ) and draw the map with time unit by 1s.

this query will draw graph like this:
[image]

The green line is `increaseUrl` and it is greater than 0 almost all the time while testing.

Here is the testing alert rule:

```
groups:
- name: automatic_flow_control
  rules:
  - alert: automatic_flow_control
    expr: deriv(label_replace({__name__=~"responseTime_.*"}, "metricname", "$1", "__name__", "(.*)")[20s:1s])>0.2
    for: 1m
    labels:
      serverity: warn
      annotations:
      summary: gateway limitation alert has invoked
      value: "value= {{ $value }}"
```

My reuirement of this rule is to invoke an alert if any metric's calculated value by the `expr` is greater than 0.2 for 1 minute.

When I reload the `prometheus.yml` and enable the rule, this rule will always pending and never fire an alert, even though `increaseUrl` will always greater than 0.2.

Although there are several points missing because `increaseUrl`'s value is less than 0.2. I'm sure that `increaseUrl` has a lot of greater-than-1m intervals that the values are keeping greater than 0.2 which will invoke the alert for sure.

If I set the threshold to `0.1` there are more and larger intervals in the graph like this, but no alerts invoked by prometheus at all:
[image]

I don't know why this happens. Are there any bugs that I missed so I cannot get any alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the problem is.

refering [this question](https://groups.google.com/g/prometheus-users/c/7Ul6ngc7Ogs/m/j_YDszV5BwAJ)

`{{ $value }}` should not put in the alert rule. just remove that line, the problem is not showing again.

new alert rule shall be:

```
groups:
- name: automatic_flow_control
  rules:
  - alert: automatic_flow_control
    expr: deriv(label_replace({__name__=~"responseTime_.*"}, "metricname", "$1", "__name__", "(.*)")[20s:1s])>0.2
    for: 1m
    labels:
      serverity: warn
      annotations:
      summary: gateway limitation alert has invoked
      #remove this line below
      #value: "value= {{ $value }}"
```